# "Setting up workspace: Loading packages..." takes too long

Tags: go, visual-studio-code

Every time I open the project folder in VSCode, it starts with "Setting up workspace: Loading packages...". If I run VSCode not as Administrator (windows 11) it will end up with this message:

```
Error loading workspace: 1 modules have errors: nuxt-fetch-bug:pattern nuxt-fetch-bug/...: open C:\Users\username\AppData\Local\ElevatedDiagnostics: Access is denied.
```

I don't understand what it has to do with nuxt actually. I am trying to open the folder with the single file - main.go.

Most annoying part of this is that I can't save files until it is ended, or even write code, because there is no autocompletion or anything else.

Answer (score 4):

Damn, figured that out. This happens when you open the project that don't have go.mod file.

`go mod init example` solved the issue.